# Why POST Request from POSTMAN returns empty?

Tags: php, laravel, post, postman, lumen

My header in the postman like this :

[image]

My body like this :

[image]

In the routes laravel lumen, I check like this :

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    ...
    $router->post('/sales-order', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        echo '<pre>';print_r($request->all());echo '</pre>';die();
    });
});
```

The result in the postman return empty array like this :

[image]

How can I solve the error?

Comment: please `dd($request->all())` and show it to us

Comment: @Vladyslav Startsev It's the same. The result is empty

Comment: OK then in index.php var_dump($_POST);die; if it's still empty, your not sending data

Comment: @VladyslavStartsev raw JSON won't appear in `$_POST`. OP would need to try `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` but Laravel may have already consumed that stream (it can only be read once). OP would need to put the debug code first

Comment: @Vladyslav Startsev Where is index.php? I using lumen laravel

Comment: @Phil I'm still confused. What the solution?

Comment: If you `return 'hello';` Do you get anything back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DUDE! I finally realize your parameters is wrong

`"number": ""123""` you put 2 double quote it should `"number": "123"`

Comment: It works. But this : https://postimg.cc/image/dt5ihpoh3/.  Which I mark, it becomes text. No json

Comment: then modify your backend

Comment: Okay.  But I see here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/post-request-from-postman-returns-null. It can use json and works. But why my postman is not works?

Comment: whats the result anyway? screen shot it, seems the problem is in your backend

Comment: @SuccessMan try this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21219626/3481654

`Input::all();` or `$request->json()->all();`

Comment: try `$request->json()->all();`  this then make it json again

Comment: If use `Input:all();`,  it's the same

Comment: did you make it json again?

Comment: It does not work. If use `Content-Type application/json` the result empty

Comment: @SuccessMan at the beginning your code is just okay, its just you put an invalid json parameter just look at the postman there's a `x` mark which mean that format is incorrect and still it can display only by text

Comment: Great. I really don't see that. But thanks a lot. It works. Have a nice day :)